# Why is Capybara test output using 100% cpu for minutes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, performance, integration-testing, capybara, cpu-usage

We've got a fairly large test suite with lots of integration tests, with the following setup:

- REE ree-1.8.7-2011.03 under RVM
- test/unit with shoulda 2.11.3
- integration tests with capybara 1.0.0 in rack/test mode
- Rails 3.0.10
- spree 0.60.0

Occasionally, but not always, after running the integration test (via rake test:integration) and a couple of test failures or errors, the ruby process with the tests will hang for minutes with full CPU (well, core) utilization, apparantly churning away on something, and then finally display the error output.

My Google-Fu fails here.

Does anybody have suggestions or know of bugs in this area ?

Comment: Some day I've found that stability of Capybara tests is bound to driver of your choice.  I had strange errors frequently when I was using chromedriver, but after I switched to selenium, they were appearing very rarely (though still).